# How to wrap existing event handler without modifying "this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some existing code that has an form submit handler:

```
function AjaxFormSubmit(e) {
 [...]
 var form = $(this);
 [...]
}
```

To bind the handler in my view code I have this:

```
$('myForm').submit(AjaxFormSubmit);
```

What I want to do is run some other code before calling AjaxFormSubmit with something like this:

```
$('myForm').submit(function(e) {
doSomething();
AjaxFormSubmit(e);
});
```

The problem is that in AjaxFormSubmit, the call to **$(this)** doesn't get the form element. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be sure `this` gets called in the right context.

```
$('myForm').submit(function(e) {
  doSomething();
  AjaxFormSubmit.call(this, e);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('myForm').submit(function(e) {
doSomething();
AjaxFormSubmit.call(this, e);
});
```